# Barba.js triggering transition on anchor links

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, barbajs

quite noob user of Barba.js here.

I am using Barba.js on a **Joomla** website, and almost everything is working fine.

My problem is that Barba.js is **triggering** the page transition also on my **anchor** links, and it redirects to the homepage.

```
<a href="#section3">Click here</a>
```

This is the element that I have on my mydomain.com/index.php/secondPage

When I click on the element, the site barba-transitions to mydomain.com/**index.php#section3**

**But** if I go to my *secondPage* and **refresh** the page, the anchor link works perfectly.

What am I missing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla-related questions there.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I definitely think that this issue is not joomla-related.

Comment: Sure.  It is certainly possible that someone without Joomla expertise can resolve your problem.  There are unforeseeable scenarios where a fellow Joomla user may have advice that leverages best practices within the context of a Joomla environment.  This is why all questions relating to Joomla and its many extensions are all on-topic at JSE.  Even if you prefer to keep your question here, I hope that we will see you at JSE in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want certain links to be processed by Barba.js you can add a class to them - so the Barba knows it's not Barba business.
For example - add prevent-barba class and then in Barba init function parameters add:

```
prevent: ({ el }) => el.classList && el.classList.contains('prevent-barba'),
```

Hope that helps :)